# Getting fastest path on a grid

Tags: xna, 2d, grid

How would I go about finding the fastest path to connect two points on a grid? I'm making a 2D game and the map is based around a grid.

I need to be able to account for any blocked tiles that the path need be able to go through.

Example: https://i.stack.imgur.com/EHUTq.jpg 
The blue line being what I need to figure out, and the red tiles being the blocked tiles.

Where should I start? Any advice be would great!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Sounds like you want A-star path-finding, which is pretty much the defacto for path-finding. I used this in my XNA game: http://www.csharpcity.com/reusable-code/a-path-finding-library/ (I repackaged the library into a slightly more usable stand-alone DLL).

Comment: This looks exactly like what i need. Thanks for the quick reply. :)